# Where / which is the actual kernel source?

Tags: apt, kernel, source-code

I am following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to learn to compile the kernel. I used

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

to download the source code of the Linux kernel I am curretly using.

After running the above command, the following files (and directories) were downloaded.

```
user $ ls -l
total 130972
drwxrwxr-x 27 sps sps      4096 Oct 16 03:10 linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0
-rw-rw-r--  1 sps sps  10980684 Oct  5 10:54 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.diff.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 sps sps      7396 Oct  5 10:54 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.dsc
-rw-rw-r--  1 sps sps 123115155 May  6 21:35 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz
user $
```

In the [same](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) page it is mentioned:

> Building the kernel is quite easy. Change your working directory to the root of the kernel source tree and then type the following commands:

But I am not sure which is the "root of the kernel source tree".

Is it the current directory (where I ran `apt-get source ...` and where I have the above listed files)?

Or, is it the directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x 27 sps sps      4096 Oct 16 03:10 linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0
```

or, should I extract the tarball

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 sps sps 123115155 May  6 21:35 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz
```

Output for `uname -r`:

```
user $ uname -r
3.19.0-30-generic
user $
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcePackage):

> **Source packages** provide you with all of the necessary files to compile or otherwise, build the desired piece of software.
>
> It consists, in its simplest form, of three files:
>
> - The upstream tarball with **.tar.gz** ending
> - A description file with .dsc ending. It contains the name of the package, both, in its filename as well as content (after the Source: keyword).
> - A tarball, with any changes made to upstream source, plus all the files created for the Debian package.
>
>   - This has a **.debian.tar.gz** (source format : 3.0)
>   - or a **.diff.gz** ending (source format : 1.0)

It's quite the same for Ubuntu, and in your case:

- **"linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0": the actual kernel**, patched starting from the upstream tarball "linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz" with the modifications listed in "linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.diff.gz";
- "linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.diff.gz": a tarball, with any changes made to upstream source, plus all the files created for the Debian package;
- "linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.dsc": a descrition file ".dsc" ending. It contains the name of the package, both, in its filename as well as content (after the Source: keyword);
- "linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz": the upstream tarball with ".tar.gz" ending (mind that in my experience it's not always a ".tar.gz" file, it can be in slightly different formats, such as ".tar.xz");

When you run `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`, the upstream tarball is automatically patched with the modifications listed in "linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.diff.gz" in "linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0":

```
% apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
# ...
dpkg-source: info: extracting linux in linux-3.19.0
dpkg-source: info: unpacking linux_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying linux_3.19.0-30.34.diff.gz
# ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The root of your kernel tree is the directory `linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0`.

About the other files:

In the tarball `linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz` you can find the "vanilla" kernel, as released upstream; to this kernel the Ubuntu developers have added patches, drivers, changed things that are collected in the `diff` which is compressed in `linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1.diff.gz`.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm. When you run the command

```
apt-get source linux-image-`uname -r`
```

the command should **automatically** extract the source tarballs and patch them to create a directory called after your kernel. In your case, it looks like it is called 'linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0' - it is there in your directory listing.

So, that is the source directory, you should run:

```
cd linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0
```

and then continue to follow the instructions